# Why is the WHERE returning 0 rows?

Tags: mysql

```
select item_id, item_price, discount_amount, quantity, 
  item_price * quantity AS price_total, 
  discount_amount * quantity AS discount_total, 
 (item_price - discount_amount) * quantity AS item_total

from order_items

WHERE 'item_total' > 500.00

ORDER BY item_total DESC;
```

this is my query and for some reason the WHERE statement just shows up empty. I've tried without the '' and just get errors, but when I remove the WHERE altogether it returns 12 rows fine, so I'm not sure why this simple line just returns nothing.

Comment: Do you have sample data that you can share?

Comment: show the error msg that you got

Comment: im not sure how I can include what it's returning. there is no error message, it just says "returned 0 rows"

Comment: can you print the 12 rows you get without WHERE clause?

Comment: You have `item_total` in quotes. So you're comparing the string to a number.

Comment: if i remove the ' from item total i get error code 1054

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can't use an alias you defined in the `SELECT` in the `WHERE` clause at the same level of the query.  MySQL has overloaded `HAVING` to make this possible:

```sql
SELECT item_id, item_price, discount_amount, quantity, 
       item_price * quantity AS price_total, 
       discount_amount * quantity AS discount_total, 
       (item_price - discount_amount) * quantity AS item_total
FROM order_items
HAVING item_total > 500.00
ORDER BY item_total DESC;
```

The reason your current query is running is that MySQL is interpreting `item_total` as a string literal, so the expression `'item_total' > 500.00` actually means something (though not what you think, and apparently it isn't true).